# Best way to optimise re-creating header in network layer

Tags: ios, swift, performance, optimization

My app makes api calls very frequently and every time creating the header part with some details

Types of header details

1. Token's that may change in between
2. Unchanged values like device model
3. Values that change with version: Version name & Bundle Number
4. Values that I fetch from user defaults

My code looks like:

```
var header: [String: Any] = [:]
header[Constant.Token] = getToken() // Can be changed during each call
header[Constant.Model] = getModel() // Device model remains same
header[Constant.Version] = getVersion() // Fetch version
header[Constant.Build] = getBuild() // Fetch build
..
..
..
..
..
..
....

// Attach header
```

What is the right way to use some hash values and find the diff,, and make the dictionary from scratch when it is required only then.

Comment: Seems you need a caching mechanism to get same token back if value isn’t changed and keep adding new one if it’s not present, by optimising space storage at same time. You can implement your own data structure called LRU cache, it can help you with space optimisation and still give you O(1) access. You can google it once, and check if that’s what you really need.

Answer (score 2):

For the information that doesn't change like app version, build number etc.
you don't have to read/create these header values for each api call.

You can initialize them as `defaultHTTPHeaders` once and use for all api calls.

```
let defaultHTTPHeaders: [String: Any] = {
   return [
       Constant.Model : getModel(),
       Constant.Version : getVersion(),
       Constant.Build : getBuild(),
   ]
}()
```

For the information that can change like `Constant.Token`, you can keep doing what you are today. So your updated implementation could look like -

```
var headers = self.defaultHTTPHeaders
headers[Constant.Token] = getToken()
```

In this way, you are repeating this task for the necessary headers (that can change) only.